# Spark Datasets - Full Outer Join Issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.0.0 with DataFrames API (DataSet[Row]) to join some dataframes as follows. I want to get all the rows from both usages and activations (hence the full outer join) and then do an inner join on the resulting dataset so that I consider only the rows that are also having a corresponding row in appDetails dataset (hence the inner join).

```
val result = usages
      .join(activations, Seq("DATE", "APP_ID"), "outer")
      .join(appDetails, Seq("APP_ID"), "inner")
```

This query does not return any results. However, if I change the full outer join to a left outer join, like this, it returns results.

```
val result = usages
      .join(activations, Seq("DATE", "APP_ID"), "left")
      .join(appDetails, Seq("APP_ID"), "inner")
```

However this doesn't work for me because I want all the rows from activations table as well. What's happening here? Why doesn't the full outer join work as expected in this case?

Comment: found any solution to this ? having similar issues

Comment: It looks like this was fixed in 2.0.1 and 2.1.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16991